# how do i print HTML table using asp.net. Header and footer on each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have htmltable which dynamically generated. I want to print this table. which consist lot of pages. when I used window.print() its printing into 7, 8 pages. but my problem is I need Header and footer on each page (A4 size). how can Set header and footer to each page.
I am using asp.net with C#.

I put header and footer on .aspx page but problem is that data is binding dynamic when I print then print goes multiple pages (ie 4 or 5 pages depend on data). So header come on first page and footer on last page I need header and footer on each page

Please provide me any suggestion or alternate way to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
I tried this solution its working.

<style type="text/css">
@media print {
thead { display: table-header-group; }
tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
}
@media screen {
thead { display: block; }
tfoot { display: block; }
}

 </style>


 <body>
 <table>
 <thead><tr><td>Your header goes here</td></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>
   Page body in here -- as long as it needs to be
   </td></tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot><tr><td>Your footer goes here</td></tr></tfoot>
 </table>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *absolutely* have to have a header/footer, you will need to insert a page break into every X table cell, where X is the number of cells you want to appear on each page. The page break will have to duplicate your header and footer.

So, your table will look like this:

```
HEADER
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell Data</td></tr>
  <!-- A bunch of rows -->
  <tr><td>Cell Data</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Cell Data
    <div class="pagebreak">
      <div>FOOTER</div>
      <!-- Print page will break here -->
      <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Cell Data</td></tr>
  <!-- A bunch of rows -->
  <tr><td>Cell Data</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Cell Data
    <div class="pagebreak">
      <div>FOOTER</div>
      <!-- Print page will break here -->
      <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
FOOTER
```

And then add the following style to your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media all
{
    .pagebreak  { display:none; }
}
@media print
{  
    .pagebreak  { display:block; }
    .pagebreak div.header  { display:block;page-break-before:always; }
}
</style>
```

Edit: I updated the HTML to (hopefully) make it more clear what needed to be done.

Comment: Paul Thanks for your help I checked your solution the only problem I am phasing about this example I am putting header,footer and page break manually in each cell. suppose my cell have three lines then also page will break after 3 lines. If data of TD line not fit into on page(A4) then also page footer will go to next page. If you have any solution then please suggest.

Comment: I wouldn't put the header/footer tags in each table row. Assuming your data is tabular in nature, what you want to do is try to estimate how many rows will fit on a single page (x), and then insert the tags every x rows. However, if you have single cells that are spanning multiple pages, this solution won't help.

Answer (score -1):

You create  a master page in which you define header area and footer area and take one div in each area and access that div in code behind page and put your generated html in the div
like this way--**div.InnerHtml=="you string containing html table"**

Comment: I have master page. In master page 2 views are their.In second view one html table one is dynamically generating and displaying in div like that only (div.InnerHtml). but this html table have header content and footer portion that is generating dynamically. and I want print this. i used window.print but for show header and footer on each page what can i do.

Comment: Master Pages won't fix a printing problem.